# SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5 Protocol mismatch. On Raspberry Pi web server

Tags: linux, server, raspberry-pi

I had setup a web server on my raspberry pi that was accessible by a domain name. I needed to add Https access to it, so I got a SSL certificate and I followed the steps and instead of having an https domain name, I got this error, `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5 Protocol mismatch`
Ive tried to undo everything from the SSL certificate initializing steps, but I still get this error.

I can ssh into the pi still over wifi and when I run `nc -zv my.hostname.com 80`  it says that the connection succeeded. Likewise, I checked canyouseeme.org and my port 80 is not being blocked

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Btw figured out the problem. I added some extra code in a config file in the ssh folder that caused problems. Got rid of the unecessary code and bam! Problem solved.